# Shadow on CardView within ConstraintLayout not showing

Tags: android, android-cardview, shadow, android-constraintlayout

I have a `CardView` within a `ConstraintLayout`.

This view is then inflated and added to a `LinearLayout`.

I would like the `CardView` to cast a shadow on the next `CardView`, but it seems to be clipped by the `ConstraintLayout`. How can I get the `elevation` shadow to show on the `CardView` *without* providing more padding or margins for it?

i.e. How can I cast the shadow on an adjacent item?

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout>
        <CardView> <-- This view's shadow is cut
        ...
        </CardView>
    </ConstraintLayout>

    <ConstraintLayout>
        <CardView>
        ...
        </CardView>
    </ConstraintLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add the line of code which you are using inside CardView

Comment: Why do you have to use `ConstraintLayout` in this case.

Comment: I'm using a constraintLayout because I need the transition animations associated with it.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding this comment inside your card view that's enough

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: Beware that using `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding` will add extra padding inside the CardView, causing the content to be pushed inwards.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the elevation shadow to show on the CardView without providing more padding or margins for it?
>
> i.e. How can I cast the shadow on an adjacent item?

You can't, for both a practical reason and a conceptual one.

The practical reason comes down to how the Android framework draws `CardView` shadows. On older API levels, the card is inset within its own bounds and that extra space is used to draw the shadow. So even if you had two cards *immediately* next to each other, they'd still have "space" between them due to these insets. From the documentation:

> Before Lollipop, CardView adds padding to its content and draws shadows to that area.

On Lollipop and higher, shadows are drawn within the parent's bounds, not within the `CardView`'s bounds. Still, the parent will clip the shadow if there isn't enough space between the card's edges and the parent's edges to draw the whole shadow. In your example, each `CardView` is in a separate parent, so even if you put those parents *immediately* next to each other, each parent would still clip its card's shadow.

As for the conceptual reason, that's just not how shadows work (in nature). If you have two cards at the same elevation, even if they're right next to each other, the top card wouldn't cast a shadow on the bottom card.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
app:cardElevation="10dp"
```

In order to use `app:cardElevation` you have to add to your LinearLayout:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I tried this in a test project and the elevation should work this way. Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="ro.helpproject.funcode.help.MainActivity">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST TEST" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST TEST" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Card elevation works, but if the views are right next to each other it is still cut off. The idea is that the shadow should be on top of the following item.

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` needs padding around it for shadow to appear.

If `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` adds the shadow for you but you don't want the extra padding from 4 directions (LRTB), you need to add margin to the `CardView` yourself.

Enable `Developer options` -> `Show layout boundaries` and if you see that there is no empty space around your CardView. Then that's probably the reason shadow not appearing.